# How do /oauth/authorize and /oauth/token interact in Spring OAuth?

Tags: spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am doing an in-depth study of Spring OAuth, and I found some conflicting information.

Specifically, [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnJsspvxE1c) states that the `/oauth/token` endpoint handles the username and password before granting a refresh token to the client app.  By contrast, the [Spring OAuth Developer Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) mentions the `/oauth/authorize` and `/oauth/token` endpoints, but yet does not get specific about how they work.

Does the `/oauth/authorize` do 100% of the `username/password/nOtherFactors` check and then signal the `/oauth/token` endpoint to send a refresh token to the client, so that the client then sends the refresh token to the `/oauth/token` endpoint?

Or is all of it handled by the `/oauth/token` endpoint?

Is the relationship between `/oauth/authorize` and `/oauth/token` different for different grant types?  How?

Comment: I have removed two images from this, where the image host has died. If you can get those images again, please put them them on the official CDN.

Answer (score 22):

Per the OAuth 2.0 specification the authorize and token endpoints have different purposes.

Authorization endpoint is where the resource owner (user) logs in and grants authorization to the client (ex: web application running in the browser or an app running on a mobile device). This is typically used in scenarios where the resource owner's user agent (ex: browser) is redirected to the identity server (authorization server) for authentication. The resource owner's user agent will have direct access to the access token.

Token endpoint is where the client (ex: Server side API or mobile app) calls to exchange the Authorization Code, Client Id and Client Secret for an access token. In this scenario, the user agent is provided with an Authorization code only, no direct access to the access token. The client is a trusted party with access to client Id and Client secret from the authorization server (That is why I mentioned Server side API as the client).

Please read [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/endpoints.html) article that has even better explanation.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for providing an explanation with a link.  Lemme look into it a little further when I have time.  I am curious to find out whether the answer to this OP is different for different grant types.  However, I do not expect you to write a dissertation about it.

Comment: Excellent! I know this answer is already slightly older, but thanks for the short explanation! Especially if one uses Spring Security 5 + OAuth2Client, one gets a ton of endpoints *just like that* - which makes an application based on those libraries harder to understand and customize.